# Dealing with &T when only T has trait impl

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Let's say I have this trait:

```
pub trait DoSomething {
  fn do_it(value: Self);
}
```

And I implement it for some types:

```
impl DoSomething for i32 {
   // ...
}

impl<'a> DoSomething for &'a BigStruct {
  // ...
}
```

Great, I now take small integers by value and BigStruct by reference!

However, I run into a problem when I try to do this:

```
fn do_something_each<Items, E>(items: Items)
  where
    Items: IntoIterator<Item = E>,
    E: DoSomething,
{
    items.into_iter().for_each(|x| E::do_it(x));
}
```

This works fine:

```
let items = vec![make_big_struct(1), make_big_struct(2)];
do_something_each(&items);
```

The problem is if I do this:

```
let integers = vec![1, 2, 3];
do_something_each(&integers);
```

...the compiler will complain about `&i32` not implementing trait `DoSomething`. This is true of course, and it makes complete sense given that IntoIterator for `&Vec<T>` returns an iterator where the target is `&T`.

My first idea was to have a blanket implementation for `&T`:

```
impl<'a, T> DoSomething for &'a T {
    fn do_it(value: &T) {
        T::do_it(*value)
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work since it conflicts with another blanket imlementation that I really want to have:

```
impl<T: DoSomethingElse> DoSomething for T {
 // ...
}
```

So how do I make `do_something_each` work with iterables returning both references and non-references?

Comment: Why don't you just pass in something that does satisfy the bound `do_something_each(integers.iter().copied())`

Comment: @cafce25 I could, but I believe it would be more ergonomic in my particular context to not have to make the distinction.

Comment: I stumbled across this myself already, and I would also be interested in a solution.

Comment: Implementing this easily in safe rust might be impossible since `T` implicitly means ownership, and `&T` is an immutable borrow. I wonder if there exists a simple solution.

Comment: You cannot have the blanket implementation, but this doesn't prevent you from implementing the trait for `&i32`, and any other reference to `Copy` type you want.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I can actually use a blanket implementation in my particular case. The blanket implementation I already had was essentially:

```
pub trait AsDoable {
  type Doable: DoSomething;

  fn as_doable(&self) -> Doable;
}

impl<T> DoSomething for T
  where
    T: AsDoable
{
    fn do_it(value: Self) {
      T::Doable::do_it(value.as_doable())
    }
}
```

Well, I cannot add another blanket impl for `DoSomething` but I can add it for `AsDoable`:

```
impl<T> AsDoable for &T
  where T: DoSomething
{
  type Doable = T;

  fn as_doable(&self) -> T {
    *self
  }
}
```

Of course, the real example is not exactly like this but it's similar. The was that my blanket implementation was built on another trait and I could do the blanket reference implementation on that instead.

Answer (score -8):

Currently, I have no idea how to achieve this in safe rust. But I have come up with an answer using unsafe rust:

```rust
impl<'a, T: DoSomething> DoSomething for &'a T {
    fn do_it(value: &T) {
        T::do_it(unsafe { std::ptr::read(value) })
    }
}
```

`std::ptr::read` is used here to read the value without moving it. Thus, we can read and execute `T::do_it` without error.

The complete code is here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1650d47ac3fec6392ea56ca9155f2a76

Comment: If your T is so trivial that ptr::Read is sound to do, you should just derive copy and let the compiler handle it, otherwise you just got yourself a double free.

Comment: ...and this doesn't handle the requirement of the another blanket impl.